# How can I write the value of k for periods from 0 to 50 into a csv-file?

Tags: python, csv

I wrote this code:

```
delta, s, theta = 0.08, 0.3, 0.35
k = 2.5
for i in range(1,51):
    k = (1 - delta) * k + s * k ** theta
    print(f"{i:3d}: {k}")    

import csv
with open('capital.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
     fieldnames = ['col1', 'col2']
     writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
     writer.writeheader()
     for a, b in range(i,k)
         writer.writerow({'col1': a, 'col2': b})
```

I would like to see in the Excel document the value of `i` from 0 to 50 in the first column and the value of `k` in the second column.

Comment: in the preparation part, `k` is a single variable, which is constantly overwritten. In the last `for` loop, there are missing colon, invalid tuple extraction from `range` (intention seems to go from `enumerate(k, 1)`, and missing indent

Comment: But how can I extract the 2 values I need in the csv-file from the preparation part?

Comment: See CodeTerapy's answer, he got it right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I get it right, you want 2 columns. one is the range of numbers from 1 to 51 and the second one is  the calculated value (k)
this would make it happen:

```
import csv

delta, s, theta = 0.08, 0.3, 0.35
k = 2.5
with open('capital.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(['col1', 'col2'])
    writer.writerow([0, k])
    for i in range(1, 51):
        k = (1 - delta) * k + s * k ** theta
        writer.writerow([i, k])
```

Comment: please consider accepting this as the right asnwer

Comment: I would like also to see for the number 0 the value of k=2,5.  What can I do?

Comment: You mean you want the for loop start from zero?

Comment: If so, just changed the 1 to 0 in range function, or just use range(51)

Comment: If I do this it appears k=2,7 as 0 but I need k=2,5 as 0 and k=2,7 as 1

Comment: I'm not aware of your math equation, but you can simply put a condition that if i==0, write 2.5. I changed the code a bit to fit your requirements.